# How do I sync contacts on my iPhone to Ubuntu-One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, iphone, contacts

When I open the U1 iPhone app the only options I have are to upload photos.
I don't have any music on my phone but would like to sync my contacts.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2011/05/09/some-changes-to-contacts-2/

> As of June 1, 2011 the current Ubuntu One contacts sync for mobile will no longer be active. We’re stopping support for our current service so we can focus our energy on launching a much better service sooner than we could otherwise.

Comment: Any idea when contact syncing will be available again?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [tutorial](http://maketecheasier.com/sync-iphone-contacts-to-ubuntu-one/2010/06/28) on syncing your iphone contacts with Ubuntu One.  If any questions or if I can be of further assistance just let me know!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @coversnail thank you very much for the comment...I'm still learning with the forums and appreciate the link for the etiquette.  For the help you get +1!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help but it appears the tutorial is outdated. By the looks of it I'll just have to wait until the new service arrives.